# How can I check the version of tinytex installed on my windows system?

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto, tinytex

I am using tinytex latex compiler to create PDF documents in RStudio. This TinyTeX is dependent on TeX Live. Recently, TeX Live was freezed and new version of TeX Live was released. Therefore, I also uninstalled and reinstalled TinyTex. Now I want to check with TinyTeX version is installed on my system. How can I check it?
In R, there is a package called tinytex, which is maintained by the same developer, Yihui Xie, who has developed TinyTeX latex compiler. So, using tinytex package, I used

```
tinytex::is_tinytex()
```

But it only shows me that my system has TinyTeX latex compiler. How can I know which version of this Latex package manager I have installed? Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check this using `tinytex` package with `tlmgr_version` function like this:

```r
library(tinytex)
tinytex::tlmgr_version()
#> tlmgr revision 63068 (2022-04-18 07:58:07 +0200)
#> tlmgr using installation: /Users/quinten/Library/TinyTeX
#> TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2022
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. It is working for me. I got tlmgr revision 66457 (2023-03-08 00:07:12 +0100).